# Filter rows in PostgreSQL based on values of consecutive rows in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm working with the following postgresql table:

10 rows from PostGreSQL table
[image]

For each business_id, I want to filter out those businesses where the review_count isn't above a specific review_count threshold for **2 consecutive months (or rows)**. Depending on the city the business_id is in, the threshold will be different (so for example, in the screenshot above, we can assume rows with city = Charlotte has a review_count threshold of >= 2, and those with city = Las Vegas has a review_count threshold of >= 3. **If a business_id does not have at least one instance of consecutive months with review_counts above the specified threshold, I want to filter it out.**

I want this query to return only the business_ids that meet this condition (as well as all the other columns in the table that go along with that business_id). The composite primary key on this table is (business_id, year, month).

Some months, as you may notice, are missing from the data (month 9 of the second business_id). If that is the case, I do NOT want to count 2 rows as 'consecutive months'. For example, for the business in Las Vegas, I do NOT want to consider month 8 to 10 as 'consecutive months', even though they appear in consecutive rows.

I've tried something like this, but have kind of run into a wall and don't think its getting me far:

```
SELECT *
FROM us_business_monthly_review_growth
WHERE business_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(business_id)
                      FROM us_business_monthly_review_growth
                      GROUP BY business_id, year, month
                      HAVING (city = 'Las Vegas' 
                             AND (CASE WHEN COUNT(review_count >= 2 * 2.21) >= 2))
                             OR (city = 'Charlotte' AND (CASE WHEN COUNT(review_count >= 2 * 1.95) >= 2))
```

I'm new to Postgre and StackOverflow, so if you have any feedback on the way I asked this question please don't hesitate to let me know! =)

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to some help from @[Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff), I found the following solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM us_businesses_monthly_growth_and_avg
WHERE business_id IN (SELECT distinct(business_id)
FROM (SELECT *,
             lag(year) OVER (PARTITION BY business_id ORDER BY year, month) AS prev_year,
             lag(month) OVER (PARTITION BY business_id ORDER BY year, month) AS prev_month,
             lag(review_count) OVER (PARTITION BY business_id ORDER BY year, month) AS prev_review_count
      FROM us_businesses_monthly_growth_and_avg 
     ) AS usga
WHERE (city = 'Charlotte' AND review_count >= 4 * 1.95 AND prev_review_count >= 4 * 1.95 AND (YEAR * 12 + month) = (prev_year * 12 + prev_month) + 1)
        OR (city = 'Las Vegas' AND review_count >= 4 * 3.31 AND prev_review_count >= 4 * 3.31 AND (YEAR * 12 + month) = (prev_year * 12 + prev_month) + 1);
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: Do you want it to return all rows corresponding to a `business_id` that meets the criteria or just those rows that are consecutive and possessing a sufficient review count?

Comment: Yes correct @toonice I want it to return **all** the rows corresponding to a business_id

Comment: As a suggestion, it would be nice if you would post a script for the creation and population of sample tables and sample data, if such is available or readily creatable, when posting the question.  Although this is not always required or missed, it does help someone developing an Answer to test their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `lag()`:

```
select distinct business_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(year) over (partition by business_id order by year, month) as prev_year,
             lag(month) over (partition by business_id order by year, month) as prev_month,
             lag(rating) over (partition by business_id order by year, month) as prev_rating
      from us_business_monthly_review_growth t
     ) t
where rating >= $threshhold and prev_rating >= $threshhold and
      (year * 12 + month) = (prev_year * 12 + prev_month) + 1;
```

The only trick is setting the threshold value.  I have no idea how you plan on doing that.

Comment: @Gordan awesome! Just to clarify, you are saying you aren't sure how to set different thresholds based on the 'city' value? Just want to make sure I interpreted that correctly, this is an awesome start though!

Comment: Also, wouldn't this only return the business_ids that meet the condition? I am actually looking to return the **"the other columns in the table that go along with that business_id)"** Each row is uniquely identified by a combination of (business_id, year, month), which is the primary key.

Comment: @dsc03 . . . I would suggest using `join`, `exists`, or `join` to get the other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try...

```
SELECT business_id
FROM
(       
    SELECT business_id AS business_id,
           LAG( business_id, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS lag_in_business_id,
           city,
           LAG( year, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) * 12 + LAG( month, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS diffInDates,
           review_count AS review_count
    FROM us_business_monthly_review_growth
        order BY business_id,
                 year,
                 month
) tempTable
JOIN tblCityThresholds ON tblCityThresholds.city = tempTable.city
WHERE business_id = lag_in_business_id
  AND diffInDates = 1
  AND tblCityThresholds.threshold <= review_count
GROUP BY business_id;
```

In formulating this answer I first used the following code to test that `LAG()` performed as hoped...

```
SELECT business_id,
       LAG( business_id, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS lag_in_business_id,
       year,
       month,
       LAG( year, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) * 12 + LAG( month, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS diffInDates
FROM mytable
ORDER BY business_id,
         year,
         month;
```

Here I was trying to get `LAG()` to refer to values on the next row, but the output showed that it was referring to the previous row in that comparison.  Unfortunately I wanted to compare current values with the next one to see if the next record had the same `business_id`, etc.  So I changed the `1` in `LAG()` to `-1', giving me...

```
SELECT business_id,
       LAG( business_id, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS lag_in_business_id,
       year,
       month,
       LAG( year, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) * 12 + LAG( month, -1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY business_id, year, month ) AS diffInDates
FROM mytable
ORDER BY business_id,
         year,
         month;
```

As this gave me the desired results I added `city,` to allow a `JOIN` between the results and an assumed table holding the details of each city and its corresponding threshold.  I chose the name `tblCityThresholds` as a suggestion since I am not sure what you have / would call it.  This completed the inner `SELECT` statement.

I then joined the results of the inner `SELECT` statement to `tblCityThresholds` and refined the output as per your criteria.  Note : It is assumed that the `city` field will always have a corresponding entry in `tblCityThresholds`;

I then used `GROUP BY` to ensure no repetition of a `business_id`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html (in regards `LAG()`)